# How to get this json data in ajax

Tags: json, ajax

```
        $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: "index.php?r=site/reportsfarm&orderdate="+fromord_date+"&farmname="+farmno,
              async:false,
              success: function(data) {
                  $.each(data,function(index,key){
                      $.each(key,function(inx,ky){
                          console.log(ky.pfs_id); 
                      });
                  });
             }
        });
```

I have used the above ajax code for getting the json data , but in console it showing the value undefined,please help any one to solve this problem....

```
[{
    "itemresult": [{
        "pfs_id": "42",
        "unitprice": "422",
        "oi_slots": "0.5 kgs",
        "qty": "1",
        "productname": "tomato"
    }, {
        "pfs_id": "65",
        "unitprice": "125",
        "oi_slots": "0.5 kgs",
        "qty": "1",
        "productname": "Beans"
    }],
    "itemresult1": [{
        "pfs_id": "42",
        "oi_slots": "0.5 kgs",
        "qty": "1"
    }, {
        "pfs_id": "65",
        "oi_slots": "0.5 kgs",
        "qty": "1"
    }, {
        "pfs_id": "42",
        "oi_slots": "2 kgs",
        "qty": "1"
    }, {
        "pfs_id": "65",
        "oi_slots": "1 kgs",
        "qty": "1"
    }, {
        "pfs_id": "42",
        "oi_slots": "0.5 kgs",
        "qty": "1"
    }, {
        "pfs_id": "65",
        "oi_slots": "1 kgs",
        "qty": "1"
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have no `dataType: "json"` property set, you get a plain string in your success callback.

Consider turning it into a JavaScript object by `JSON.parse()` or modify your ajax call to automatically do it.